# Simple way of getting current hour in a specfic time zone in modern JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the current hour (e.g. `13` if the time is 13:45) in the time zone "Europe/London", no matter the user's own time zone.

It only needs to work in modern browsers, and it's fine if the user's browser doesn't happen to handle this time zone – it's for a bit of progressive enhancement where I'm fine wrapping it in a `try`/`catch` and doing nothing if it fails.

The following was the best I could come up with.

```js
const timeZone = "Europe/London"
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", { timeZone, hour: "numeric" })
const hour = parseInt(dateTimeFormat.formatToParts(new Date)[0].value, 10)
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toLocaleString() method

```js
const hour = new Date().toLocaleString("en-GB", { timeZone: "Europe/London", hour: "numeric" });

console.log(hour)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great. To be explicit for any future readers, this returns a string – to get an integer, I did `parseInt(hour, 10)`.